# Change Fragment to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Hey I have a navigation drawer and each element opens a fragment. now i want to to open the last fragment if I press the back button.I use this .addBackStack(null) method but when I press back then I have no content and when i press the back again I have the fragment what I need. How can i get rid of this black content? 
I change my fragments like this:

```
 @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(final int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
  final  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    if(position==0)
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, KedvencekFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        }, 250);

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to save a stack with the previous fragments position

Comment: And how can i save the fragments position to the stack?

Comment: Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
                stack.push(position);
                int position = stack.pop();

Comment: Can you check by commenting the postDelayed() section. The black screen shows may be because of postDelayed block execution.